# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to\color{red}{-1^{-1}}}\sum\limits_{i=2000}^{2009}|x-i|$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\color{red}{-1^{-1}}}\sum_{i=2000}^{2009}|x-i|$$

I could not able to properly evaluate it. Can anyone help?

Comment: The absolute value function is continuous so just plug and chug.

Comment: @Felix Marin I cannot understand how u get it?

Comment: @user146181 He thought it was $\lim_{x\to \sqrt{-1}}$. But since it seems to be $(-1)^{-1} = -1$, it's simpler and yields a nice integer solution.

Comment: @user146181 Sorry. I confuse $i$ with $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer I am getting it wrong.Could u help?

Answer (score 1):

The limit is equivalent to:

$$A = \lim_{x \to -1} \sum^{2009}_{i=2000} |x-i| =  \sum^{2009}_{i=2000} | \lim_{x \to -1}(x-i)| = \sum^{2009}_{i=2000} |-1-i| = \sum^{2009}_{i=2000} |1+i| $$
Yet $1+i > 0$ so $A= \sum^{2009}_{i=2000}1+i$. Let $k := 1+i$ so $A= \sum^{2009}_{k-1=2000} k = \sum^{2010}_{k=2001} k$. We then define $a_n = 2001+(n-1)$ and $A$ becomes $\Sigma_{10} = 10* \frac{2001+2010}{2} = 5*(4011) = 20055$